# How to integrate Foxit PDF Reader in Android?

Tags: android, pdf-reader, foxit

I have followed these steps in order to compile the Foxit library:

```
1) Download and install the Eclipse IDE (http://www.eclipse.org/), the Android SDK, ADT plugin for Eclipse, and the Android NDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).
a) For Windows use, also download and install Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/). During Cygwin setup, make sure to include the “Devel -> make” package.
2) Download the Foxit embedded SDK Package.
3) Extract the Foxit embedded SDK Package to any directory.
4) Place the Foxit embedded SDK library and header files in fpdfemb_android/examples/demos/bin and include directory.
5) Build the NDK layer.
a) Open the Android.mk makefile in fpdfemb_android/examples/demos/demo(like “demo_view”)/jni/ in a text editor and fill in the Foxit library name in the area designated for LOCAL_LDLIBS, dropping the lib prefix:
The demo is shipped as:
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=../bin/# fill in library name here
To add downloaded libfoxit.a from step 2, fill in as:
LOCAL_LDLIBS :=../bin/libfoxit.a
If the library provide is not named “libfoxit.a” please adjust accordingly.
b) Open Cygwin (Windows), or a terminal (Linux based), and navigate to the fpdfemb_android/examples/demos/demo(like “demo_view”) directory. Run “ndk-build –B” to build the NDK/JNI layer.
Example:
me@myStation /myProjectPath/ > ndk-build –B
This assumes that the ndk directory is part of the $PATH environment variable. The command can also be qualified with the path to the NDK directory.
```

But then I'm getting this error in the terminal:

Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:fpdfembedsdk: non-system libraries in linker flags: jni/../../bin/libfoxit.a
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
make: *** No rule to make target `–B'.  Stop.

Could you please tell me if there is any way to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post you 'Android.mk' file

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying Foxit's new MobilePDF SDK for Android which will provide most of the functionality found in the embedded PDF SDK that you've previously tried but it includes a user interface and can be integrated into your Android projects quickly.

http://www.foxitsdk.com/products/mobile-pdf-sdk/

This SDK replaces Foxit's embedded SDK.